# What is good route template for api?

Tags: c#, api

What is good API route template?
 I other words, is there template that i  more expectable, or it is not important at all?

first: 
"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

```
http://example.com/WorkItem/details/5
```

second:
"api/{controller}/{id}/{action}"

```
http://example.com/WorkItem/5/details
```

Comment: its your wish , you can change it as you want

Comment: It depends on individual requirements and the way they want to handle routing in their application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider it good practice to use your second approach in a RESTful szenario. Common frameworks handle it this way:

### Example 1: [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

see the docs at *2.2 CRUD, Verbs, and Actions*, where

`GET /photos/{:id}/edit` refers to the `PhotosController`s `edit`-method to return an HTML form for editing a photo

### Example 2: [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

see the docs at *RESTful Resource Controllers*, where

`GET /photo/{photo}/edit` also refers to a  `PhotoController`s  `edit`-method.

Also, see the section on *Nested Resources* below which looks a bit more like your use case:

`Route::resource('photos.comments', 'PhotoCommentController');`
 registers a nested route in the way of `photos/{photos}/comments/{comments}` which is your use case and looks more like your second approach.